# Remove specific elements from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an np.array I would like to remove specific elements from based on the element "name" and not the index. Is this sort of thing possible with np.delete() ?

Namely my original ndarray is

`textcodes= data['CODES'].unique()`

which captures unique text codes given the quarter.

Specifically I want to remove certain codes which I need to run through a separate process and put them into a separate ndarray

`sep_list = np.array(['SPCFC_CODE_1','SPCFC_CODE_2','SPCFC_CODE_3','SPCFC_CODE_4])`

I have trouble finding a solution on removing these specific codes in `sep_list` from `textcodes` because I don't know exactly where these `sep_list` codes would be indexed as it would be different each quarter and I would like to automate it based on the specific names instead because those will always be the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
import numpy as np

    data = [3,2,1,0,10,5]
    bad_list = [1, 2]
    data = np.asarray(data)
    new_list = np.asarray([x for x in data if x not in bad_list])

    print("BAD")
    print(data)
    print("GOOD")
    print(new_list)
```

Yields:

```
BAD
[ 3  2  1  0 10  5]
GOOD
[ 3  0 10  5]
```

It is impossible to tell for sure since you did not provide sample data, but the following implementation using your variables should work:

```
import numpy as np

textcodes= data['CODES'].unique()
sep_list = np.array(['SPCFC_CODE_1','SPCFC_CODE_2','SPCFC_CODE_3','SPCFC_CODE_4'])

final_list = [x for x in textcodes if x not in sep_list]
```

Comment: No problem, @mattie_g. Good luck coding. If this answer helped you, please make sure to accept it so that others who have similar problems can reference it too. This helps make Stack Overflow a productive resource of programming Q&A :) (not to mention, you get more reputation points when you accept an answer!)